# Need to create data frame from patterns in a string

Tags: regex, r

I have the following string I need to extract the patterns into a single column data frame named `SIZE`

```
str <- "N · 0.1 [mm]: N · 0.1 + 0.02 [mm]: N · 0.1 + 0.05 [mm] N · 0.1 + 0.08 [mm] M · 1 [mm]: M · 1 + 0.5 [mm] M · 1 + 0.75 [mm]"
```

The patterns are either followed by `:` or `whitespace` and always ends in `[mm]`

The regex I am using to match my patterns is and it works, but i'm not sure how to extract the matches to create a column as a data frame.

```
\S\W+\d\.?\d?\s\+?\s?\d?\.?\d?\d?\s?\[mm\]
```

Output expected: 1 column named `SIZE`

```
       N · 0.1 [mm]
N · 0.1 + 0.02 [mm]
N · 0.1 + 0.05 [mm]
N · 0.1 + 0.08 [mm]
         M · 1 [mm]
   M · 1 + 0.5 [mm]
  M · 1 + 0.75 [mm]
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps, [`strsplit`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strsplit.html) would make things easier here..

```
str  <- "N · 0.1 [mm]: N · 0.1 + 0.02 [mm]: N · 0.1 + 0.05 [mm] N · 0.1 + 0.08 [mm] M · 1 [mm]: M · 1 + 0.5 [mm] M · 1 + 0.75 [mm]"
vals <- strsplit(str, '(?<=\\])[\\s:]*', perl = T)
data.frame(SIZE = unlist(vals))
```

Output

```
                 SIZE
1        N · 0.1 [mm]
2 N · 0.1 + 0.02 [mm]
3 N · 0.1 + 0.05 [mm]
4 N · 0.1 + 0.08 [mm]
5          M · 1 [mm]
6    M · 1 + 0.5 [mm]
7   M · 1 + 0.75 [mm]
```

Comment: Because of the relationship between `data.frame`s and `list`s in R, `data.frame(setNames(strsplit(str, '(?<=\\])[\\s:]*', perl = T), "SIZE"))` would also work. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach to get the data in: replace any instances of "[mm] " with "[mm]: " and `scan` the text in with ":" as your separator. No fussing with regexes....

```
scan(what = "", text = gsub("[mm] ", "[mm]: ", str, fixed=TRUE), 
     sep = ":", strip.white=TRUE)
# Read 7 items
# [1] "N · 0.1 [mm]"        "N · 0.1 + 0.02 [mm]" "N · 0.1 + 0.05 [mm]"
# [4] "N · 0.1 + 0.08 [mm]" "M · 1 [mm]"          "M · 1 + 0.5 [mm]"   
# [7] "M · 1 + 0.75 [mm]"
```

Just assign the result there to a column in a `data.frame` or create a `data.frame` with the output. Or, all in one:

```
data.frame(
  SIZE = scan(text = gsub("[mm] ", "[mm]: ", str, fixed=TRUE), 
              sep = ":", strip.white=TRUE, what = ""))
```